# Trying to shuffle a custom Stack data structure

Tags: java, stack, shuffle

I have been working on a project that simulates the "war" card game and made an original main deck and have been trying to get it shuffled with my custom stack class. I tried dividing the deck into four separate piles and using a randomized switch statement to add all the cards to one full pile similar to how people shuffle in trading card games. I have been receiving a nullPointer exception on my random number instantiation and am lost on how to fix it. I would appreciate any help!

```
        LinkedStack<Card> pileOne = new LinkedStack<Card>();
        LinkedStack<Card> pileTwo = new LinkedStack<Card>();
        LinkedStack<Card> pileThree = new LinkedStack<Card>();
        LinkedStack<Card> pileFour = new LinkedStack<Card>();
        
        int origSize = this.cards.size();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i ++) { // 52 cards in the deck (supposed to be)
            if(this.cards.isEmpty() == false) {
                pileOne.push(this.cards.peek());
                this.cards.pop();
            }
            if(this.cards.isEmpty() == false) {
                pileTwo.push(this.cards.peek());
                this.cards.pop();
            }
            if(this.cards.isEmpty() == false) {
                pileThree.push(this.cards.peek());
                this.cards.pop();
            }
            if(this.cards.isEmpty() == false) {
                pileFour.push(this.cards.peek());
                this.cards.pop();
            }
        }
        
        while(pileOne.size() != origSize) {
            int randNum = rand.nextInt(3); // <- nullpointer exception
            
            switch(randNum + 1) {
                case 1:
                    if(pileTwo.isEmpty() == false) {
                        pileOne.push(pileTwo.peek());
                        pileTwo.pop();
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if(pileThree.isEmpty() == false) {
                        pileOne.push(pileThree.peek());
                        pileThree.pop();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    if(pileFour.isEmpty() == false) {
                        pileOne.push(pileFour.peek());
                        pileFour.pop();
                    }
                    break;
            }           
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you haven't instantiated `rand` field. Local variables must be initialized if you want to use them, but it isn't the same for instance or static fields. So if you try to run a method on an undefined reference, you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

```
public Random rand = new Random();
```

Comment: Your answer is probably correct, but there is no need to make the variable public, a private instance or a local variable might be better suited.

Comment: You're right. I just put `public` to distinguish it from a local variable.